# Folder .anaconda, .conda, .ipython, .jupyter ,etc

Tags: anaconda

I already uninstall my anaconda from my laptop (OS Windows). But, there are still folder name like .anaconda, .conda, .jupyter, .keras, .matplotlib, .spyder-py3
Is it oke to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's perfectly fine to delete them.

These folder will come back with a fresh installation of anaconda and other mentioned packages.